# Eclipse Java Deployment: how to add auto-generate file to Jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, executable-jar

I have finished my project, and now I have deployed it to jar file. But I have met a problem:

My program auto generate a file (For example: data.sav) in Eclipse, it appears at the foremost project folder. When I deploy, this file doesn't contain to jar file. So, it start with no data.

After I run and do sth, it has made data.sav again. But, I don't see this file in that jar file. I say this because I hope I will overwrite my old data.sav to new data.sav.

So, please teach me, how to include "data.sav" to jar file.  I don't see this option when deploy in Eclipse.

Here is the code I want to write file:

```
ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(
    new FileOutputStream("data.sav"));
```

For more clearer why I do that. **For example**, a game has a list that contain most 10 people highscore. when you first play, no people play,yet, so I must "cheat" by write some people in this highscore list, so my program has some **"dummny player"** that has played before.

Comment: *"My program auto generate a file (For example: data.sav)"  I don't get it.  Your program apparently does this at 'run-time' when the app. is already in a Jar.  It can't write anything to the Jar at that time.  BTW - leave noise like 'Thanks :)' out of posts.

Comment: You want to change the content of the jar file?!

Comment: I have edited again. Please teach me

Comment: *"Please teach me"*  1. Learn that people don't get informed of comments unless you add @PersonName before the comment. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jars are read-only.  See [How can a Java program use files inside the .jar for read and write?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5052311/418556) for more details.

Perhaps the high-scores would be better stored using the [`Preferences`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) API.  It takes care of 'where to put the information' automatically.

Failing that, I would have the app. write the dummy scores and any subsequent real scores into a file in a sub-directory of `user.home`.  That is a place that should allow read/write to a standard Java app.

Comment: For example, I have a folder /src/. Can you tell me how to write to this folder,please. I just can write to absolutely path. When I use: `File file = new File(Model.class.getResource("/src/data.sav").toString());` error happen

Comment: You have either not read or not understood my message and linked answer.  I'm not sure how to proceed.