# Java - Writing to txt in a JAR file

Tags: java, file-io, jar, executable-jar, streamwriter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can a Java program use files inside the .jar for read and write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052311/how-can-a-java-program-use-files-inside-the-jar-for-read-and-write)

How do I write to a .txt file from a [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) java compiled project?

When I run my projects, it doesn't give errors, but it just doesn't write to the .txt inside JAR file.

I make the JAR file using:

```
netbeans clean /build tool
```

#### Code:

```
public class FileIO   {
    private File file;
    private Scanner filescScanner, lineScanner;
    private PrintWriter fileWriter;
    private String[][] data;

    public FileIO () {
        data = new String[100][2];
    }

    public String[][] getLineScores(){
        return this.loadHighscores(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("LineHighscores.txt"));
    }

    public String[][] getTimeScores(){
        return this.loadHighscores(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("TimeHighscores.txt"));
    }

    public void setLineScores( String name,String lines ){
        boolean found= false;
        data = this.getLineScores();
        for(int i = 0; i<data.length && !found ; i++){
            if(data[i][0] == null || "Niemand".equals(data[i][0])){
                data[i][0]=name;
                data[i][1]=lines;
                found=true;
            }
        }
        this.saveHighscores(this.getClass().getResource("LineHighscores.txt"),data);
    }

    public void setTimeScores(String time, String name){
        boolean found= false;
        data = this.getLineScores();
        for(int i = 0; i<data.length && !found ; i++){
            if(data[i][0] == null || "Niemand".equals(data[i][0])){
                data[i][0]=name;
                data[i][1]=time;
                found=true;
            }

        }
        this.saveHighscores(this.getClass().getResource("TimeHighscores.txt"),data);
    }

    private String[][] loadHighscores( InputStream resourceStream){
        int x=0;
        String test = "";
        try{
            filescScanner = new Scanner(resourceStream);
        }
        catch(Exception ioe){
            System.err.println(ioe);
        }

        if (filescScanner.hasNext()){
            while(filescScanner.hasNextLine()&& x<100) {
                lineScanner = new Scanner(filescScanner.nextLine());
                lineScanner.useDelimiter("-/-");

                data[x][0]=lineScanner.next();//name
                data[x][1]=lineScanner.next();//data
                x++;
            }
            lineScanner.close();
            filescScanner.close();
        }
        else{
            data[0][0] = "Niemand";
            data[0][1] = "0";
        }
        return data;
    }

    private void saveHighscores( URL resourceStream, String[][] data){
        int x=0;
        try {
            file = new File(resourceStream.toURI());
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileIO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        try {
            fileWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileIO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        if(data.length>x){
            while(data.length>x && data[x][0] != null ){
                fileWriter.println(data[x][0]+"-/-"+data[x][1]);
                x++;
            }
            fileWriter.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        FileIO file = new FileIO();
        file.setLineScores("55555555", "KoenKevin");
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot update a Jar this way as it is a file.  It's not a good idea to be altering a Jar after you released it.  Can you not use the file system to save your file?

Comment: You cant do that, you need to keep the txt outside the jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are trying to write a text file inside a jar, java is not recognizing absolute path to text file.

it will be something like

```
C:User/adom/documents/jarName.jar!/fileName.txt
```

This is not a absolute path so file could not be written. Try writing file externally.

Comment: yes, but i want the jar file to be moveable, what is a better way to save certain data in jave then ?

Answer (score 11):

You cannot do that, and even if you could do that, it is not recommendable: write to a location outside of the jar.

Answer (score 5):

Jar is an archive, which is meant to be unchanged. If you need your jar (application) to write something, write to an external source.

I suggest you make a separate folder and make your application point to that folder and do all your external activity there.