# Exporting a runnable JAR that includes the source folder of your project, as well as all other folders?

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io, jar

I am trying to export to a runnable JAR of my project that has the following structure:

```
Project
   |
   |---Source folder
   |         |
   |         |
   |     .java files
   |
   |
   |---Image folder
             |
             |
         .png files
```

The `.png` images are read inside the `.java` files using `ImageIO.read(new File("ImageFolder/image.png"));` which works fine when I run the program in Eclipse, but if I export to a runnable JAR, I get the following exception in the stacktrace:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!                                                              
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
```

Here is a screenshot of my project in Eclipse:

[image]

How can I include the `cardImages` folder in my JAR so that `new File("cardImages/10C.png")` can be read?

Comment: Have you tried making cardImages a source folder?

Comment: export with directory, read the image files using stream, 
**getClass().getResourceAsStream('cardmages/imagename')**.

Comment: @Ray that worked as a temporary fix anyway, but the answers below are definitely the correct way to do it

Comment: take a look at here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937904/java-writing-to-txt-in-a-jar-file.  really that is worst practise.

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on your project
- Select "Build path" => "Configure Build Path..."
- Check your "cardImages" folder in the new opened window

It should be extracted inside your jar.

Just a tip, for resources prefer the use of

```
    InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("resources/sample.txt");
```

Comment: And what about then writing an image? My program is loading an image from the`cardImages` folder, creating a new image using the one it loaded, and then writing the new image back into `cardImages` `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream` can only be used for reading as it returns an InputStream

Comment: There must be a hack do write files inside a jarfile, but it is not recommended to modify a jar at Runtime, you could encounter many issues. If you have to write file, the best practice is to create a folder in the same directory as the jar, and manage your file there (like putting configuration file or cardImages)
You can do it by :
C:User/adom/documents/jarName.jar!/fileName.txt 
Putting the "!" character to assume it is a jarfile.

Answer (score 0):

export with directory, read the image files using stream, `getClass().getResourceAsStream('cardmages/imagename');`

normally runnable jars, file operations are realtive to its path, where its getting excecuted. 
for ex

```
c:/myFolder>yourjar.jar
```

then 
your file trying to read from, `c:/myFolder/cardimages/imagename.`

File is a class used to access files from file system. not from inside a jar.

Comment: So I'd call it as `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream('cardImages/10C.png');)`

Comment: My program also needs to write images to the same folder, how can this be done in a similar way?