# How I write file in Jar

Tags: java, jar, getresource

I need to write "indice_corrente.txt" file. The structure is:

```
Home
  src
    Grafica
       FinestraPrincipale.java
       indice_corrente.txt
```

I need to write hello in "indice_corrente.txt" so I use this code to get Resources:

```
    String path=this.getClass().getResource("/Grafica/indice_corrente.txt").getPath();

PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(path);
```

But the string path is null because the getResource is null. Anyone can help me to resolve this?

Comment: write to a file IN a jar? why would you do that?

Comment: Try : `Home/ressources/Grafica/indice_corrente.txt`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Writing to txt in a JAR file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937904/java-writing-to-txt-in-a-jar-file)

Comment: hm, you cannot write into jar file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can an app use files inside the JAR for read and write?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052311/how-can-an-app-use-files-inside-the-jar-for-read-and-write)

Comment: The file indice_corrente.txt is in the jar is not out the jar in the same folder? is it possible write him?

Comment: you can't write to a file inside a jar. you need to build and repack a new jar with the changed file.