# Java - screenshot window while in runnable jar file not working

Tags: java, awtrobot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of my window with the following command.

```
BufferedImage screenCapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
ImageIO.write(screenCapture, "jpg", "data/file.jpg");
```

***I then use this image and send it to my discord server***

This works fine, it saves the file to the dir `data/file.jpg` and sends it to my server but when I make the file into a runnable .jar file, it doesn't work anymore

---

**UPADTE** I'm streaming it now -

I decided to stream the image, again it works when I run it through intellij, but when its a jar runnable its not working

---

`BufferedImage screenCapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));`

`ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();`
`ImageIO.write(screenCapture, "jpg", stream);`

Answer (score 1):

Is the "data" directory inside your jar?, if that is your case, I believe you can not write/create files inside a jar file.

Check this link: [Java - Writing to txt in a JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937904/java-writing-to-txt-in-a-jar-file)

You will have to save the file/image maybe in a relative path where the jar is, or in another location of your pc.

Comment: Check my post, I updated my solution, still not working

Comment: Maybe is that the external libraries are not being included into the jar.