# Get JAR path to file

Tags: java, jar

So lets say I have JAR file. User creates some text file and wants to save it. I would like to save it in "resources" folder in my JAR so user can read it later.

But how do I get path to this folder?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to try to manipulate a JAR file while your program is running from that JAR file.  It sounds like you have an [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- could you explain more about what your *actual* problem is, and why you think this is the right way to solve it?

Comment: I just want to SAVE TEXT FILE to JAR folder. How to do this?

Comment: The answer to "how to do this?" depends on **why** you want to do this.  Re-stating the question as "I just want to do X" doesn't help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a Java program use files inside the .jar for read and write?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052311/how-can-a-java-program-use-files-inside-the-jar-for-read-and-write)

Answer (score 3):

You usually *wouldn't* do this. Updating a zip file (which is what a jar file is, basically) is non-trivial. Jar files aren't designed to be updated with user content (e.g. their "documents" directory, or an application-specific directory). You should store your user's files in an appropriate directory. (Heck, in many operating systems the program files are installed read only anyway...)

Comment: But how can I know where to create such folder? In windows I could create it in Program Files but Linux doesnt have such directory. Where to store those files?

Comment: @user2102972: No, you shouldn't put it in Program Files in Windows! That's for *programs* - this is for *user content*. Ask the user, possibly starting off with their home directory.

Comment: The default directory were user-created documents should be stored is a complicated question with a long answer.  However, as a minimal effort, you can use `Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Documents")`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is a good idea but it is possible from command line ([jar command help](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html)):

```
jar cf myfile.jar dir1/file1.ext1 ;# create jar file and store file1
jar uf myfile.jar dir2/file2.ext2 ;# update jar file with file2
```

What is possible from command line should be possible thru the [Jar Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html)

Comment: Will the `jar` command work if the JAR is opened for reading by the JVM? (Also, instead of a command-line solution, there is the [`JarFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) class in the standard library.)

Comment: @DanielPryden - it will certainly happily write to the file, and reading JVM will most probably not like it