# Properties file (user settings) inside a jar file

Tags: java, properties, jar, embedded-resource, executable-jar

I have a Swing application I want to package as a jar file. I also have a properties file that I store user set properties in.

Can I store this file inside the jar file and will the application automatically write into the jar file?

I want to avoid having two files, the jar and the properties external of it.

Comment: Possibly related - [How can a Java program use files inside the .jar for read and write?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5052311/418556)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surely bundle properties file inside of `jar` , But one problem with that is, it will become kind of `read-only`. So you will not be able to write anything into it.

Answer (score 0):

You *could*, but that doesn't mean you *should*.

Instead, bundle a default properties file, but check for a user-specific set of properties.