# Java Game refering to files

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have started getting into game programming.

My question is, that when I am working with files, either parsing data, writing to files, etc.  Should I be using `relative path names, or absolute pathnames`, or something else which is better. I've heard about using jar files, but I am not sure

```
1. how that works

2. if it is a good way to do it.
```

So when developing a game that will be `cross platform`, what is the best method for managing files that the program will need to read from and write to.

Comment: See info for [tag:embedded-resource].

Comment: Internal files to be loaded by a classloader works best across all platforms (and most importantly outside eclipse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several ways in which you can ship your code as a product. the most common are

- packaging everything in one executable jar file.
- having a set of folders where you place all necessary resources.

minecraft, for example, is written in java and distributed as a single executable jar file that contains all necessary class files and resources. to run the game (assuming you have java installed) all you need to do is double-click the jar file.

read [this](http://dasha.ics.hawaii.edu/~johnson/613f99/modules/04/jar-files.html) short tutorial about how to add a main class to a jar file.

either way, always treat classes and resources in your code as if they're in your classpath. for example, if you have a my.properties file on the root of the source tree then load it by using 'my.properties'. if you put it under a 'conf' folder then use 'conf/my.properties'.
i think it is the safest way not to get lost.

are you using maven?

Answer (score 0):

The jar file is a zip of all your compiled *.class files and your resources. You can safely load your resources and even default data FROM a jar if you package your program, but you can NOT safely write data back to the jar. This detail is answered in depth already at

[How can an app use files inside the JAR for read and write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052311)

For information on how to package a jar see

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/