# Change a .properties file inside a jar from within that jar

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have runnable jar and I would like to change a properties file inside this runnable jar itself. The main aim here is that when this jar runs for the first time, it communicates with some other modules using some IPC and gets some details from the other module, so after getting some details this jar must persist those values to itself so that when it runs again next time, it must be able to use those new details.

If this is not possible, what could be the best way to do such a thing as storing these details to temporary location may a not a good way.

Comment: See (the answer to) [How can an app. use files inside the jar for read and write?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052311/how-can-an-app-use-files-inside-the-jar-for-read-and-write)

Comment: You're welcome.  Feel free to vote it up ..or down. ;)