# Fail to read file and parse with gson when the program packaged as jar

Tags: java, json, eclipse, jar, embedded-resource

So I am using json to store some data in a txt file. And I use Gson to tackle json. The program went well in eclipse. But when I packaged it into a jar, problem occrurs.

What I did first (in eclipse) is:

```
        String gsonStr = gson.toJson(masterShips);
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\master_ship.txt"));
            writer.write(gsonStr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } finally {
            if (writer != null) {
                try {
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
```

Then I copied the .txt file to eclipse and read it using this code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("master_ship.txt"));

String str = in.nextLine();
Log.toDebug(str);
in.close();
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement je = parser.parse(str);
JsonArray ja = je.getAsJsonArray();
for (int i=0; i<ja.size(); ++i) { 
    ... 
}
```

But when I put the .jar file and the .txt file in the same folder and excute, error appear. I thought there may be problems with the way of defining the path. Finally I turned to absolute path:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("D:\\master_ship.txt"));
```

Still, it works well in eclipse, but not when using jar. Then I opened the jar with command line:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.
stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malform
ed JSON at line 1 column 4
        at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:65)
        at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:45)
        at kan.util.Master.loadMasterShip(Master.java:44)
        at kan.util.Master.load(Master.java:27)
        at kan.Main.main(Main.java:22)
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLeni
ent(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 4
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1505)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1386)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:531)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:414)
        at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:60)
        ... 4 more
```

**I can be sure that the file is read successfully, because the jar can output the string it read from the file completely.** But why should Gson fail outside eclipse while doing good in eclipse.

Comment: `writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\master_ship.txt"));`  We cannot write to resources in a Jar.  They are 'read only'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson What do you mean? I really don't understand.

Comment: Whenever someone asks in a comment shorter than my own *"what do you mean?"*' I think *"WTF don't you understand?"*  Now would be a good time for more words, rather than less.

Comment: Actually what I thought is "WTF have you said to this quesion, you really read the question?", no offense

Comment: None taken.  In future, say that (to me).  You might want to tone it down a bit for people who are more sensitive than me though..

Comment: Glad that you don't go mad. Understand my real problem now?

Answer (score 2):

It has become an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource).  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

See also [How can an app use files inside the JAR for read and write?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5052311/418556)

Comment: Please read the question to the end. I correctly wrote and read the file (using debug in eclipse). But problem occurs with gson when using jar.

Comment: Eclipse probably has not put the resources into a Jar yet.  What I can tell you for sure, based on 'resource in Jar' is: A)  They are no longer `File` objects, and cannot be treated as such.  B) Jars are read only.

Comment: "But when I put the .jar file and the .txt file in the same folder and excute, error appear." `Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("D:\\master_ship.txt"));`. Actually I noticed it and I used absolute path. (and of course I copy the file to D disk!) PS. I runned the 'absolute path version' and it works well.