# Editing an xml file in a .jar

Tags: java, xml

So currently I can read and write to an xml file when I'm running the program in eclipse, but when I export it as a .jar the writing does not work any more.

```
public void addHighscores(String naam, String score){
            Document document = null;
        Element root = null;

        InputStream fis = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Highscores.xml");
        SAXBuilder sb = new SAXBuilder();
        document = sb.build(fis);
        root = document.getRootElement();
        fis.close();


        Element player = new Element("player");
        player.addContent(new Element("name").setText(naam));
        player.addContent(new Element("score").setText(score));
        root.addContent(player);
        document.setContent(root);

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path);
        XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();
        outputter.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
        outputter.output(document, writer);
        outputter.output(document, System.out);
        writer.close();}
```

That's the code for the writer. The xml file is saved in the same folder as the code, I don't understand why it can read but not write. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't write back to the jars on the classpath. What you can do, however, is add a directory to the classpath and read/write the XML file from that location. That'll work just fine for you. If this is a web app running in Tomcat, the Tomcat `lib` directory is part of the classpath by default. So one thing you can is read from say "/myapp/conf/stuff.xml" and put `myapp/conf/stuff.xml` under `lib`.

Comment: Beware, it is common that the lib directory is not writable by web application for security reasons.

Comment: Not making a webapp, but how would I go about adding a directory and reading/writing? Because again, when starting the program in eclipse and simply saying 
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("input/Highscores.xml"); works in eclipse, but not when in a jar

Answer (score 0):

After building a jar you can not edit it on the classpath. But you can definetly add a path in your classpath. You can place the files on that path and read from there. Please [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052311/how-can-an-app-use-files-inside-the-jar-for-read-and-write) .