# Read/Write to a .txt file from JAR

Tags: java, jar, javafx-2, java-io

Currently I'm developing a java application to carry out a survey. I want to read/write to a .txt file, creating a .csv to store inputted data. Below is code I have used so far to write data - Of course this makes the JAR file not portable as it has an absolute path.

```
File file = new File("C:/Files/JavaApp/src/text.text/");
FileWriter fw = null;
BufferedWriter bw = null;
try {
    fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
try {
    bw.write("blah" + ",");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
try {
    bw.newLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
try {
    bw.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

I have tried several methods such as  `ClassName.class.getResource("Text.text");` but it will always return a Reflection or a NullPointer error.

I know that writing to a file within the JAR does pose some problems, meaning I would have to point to a file outside to read/write. However I don't know how to preform this in code. I need the JAR file to be completely portable. Even if that means it must be kept within a directory, so the JAR can search for the .txt file within that directory. Or, is there another way?

If anyone can help me out, I would be very grateful.

Comment: don't know if you can use it for that, but try the package java.util.jar (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html)

Comment: and also read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5052359/3680684

Comment: It's not clear what is being asked.  The only question in this post is "Or, there is another way?".  What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can an app use files inside the JAR for read and write?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052311/how-can-an-app-use-files-inside-the-jar-for-read-and-write)

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Some good links, I hadn't seen before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read from the Jar file:  [How to read a file from jar in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369794/how-to-a-read-file-from-jar-in-java)

The file is an archive file.  It is a zip file with a .jar extension.  You shouldn't be writing to it.  If the jar file has been signed (security projected) you cannot write to it.  Changing a single bit in the file will invalidate it.

What you should do is store a default file in Jar and load that to the "user.home" folder if it is not already there.