# Using Java Web Start when main jar depends on other files

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have recently completed a java program and Im now looking into options for deploying it. I was introduced today to Java Web Start. My problem is the following: my program contains the main executable jar, a lib folder that contains the libraries which my program uses, and a couple of other folders which contain files that my program reads from and writes to. Is it possible to use Java Web Start with such a structure? All the examples I have seen on the web were simple programs made up of just one jar. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra libraries are no problem.  Just add a reference to each one in the JNLP `resources` section.

The 'loose files' are, slightly, in that loose resources cannot be referenced in a JNLP and *archives are not writable.*  But even that is fixable.  See the accepted answer to [How can an app use files inside the JAR for read and write?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5052311/418556)