# Writing to txt file in Java projects folders

Tags: java

I'm working on a Java project. Just one value is stored in a txt file in this location: `(src/files/file.txt)`.

I export the project to jar file and I know that beacuase of the src folder, I need to use the following code to read the file.

```
InputStream stream = MainUi.class.getResourceAsStream("src/files/tax.txt");
```

But I have problem with writing to file in such a situation, the file data is needed to be changed. Please let me know how to solve it.

Comment: resource are readonly. you have to store it some where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I export the project to jar file and I know that because of the src
>   folder, I need to use the following code to read the file.

It is not possible for your program (launched from an executable `Jar`) to write to the text file located inside same `Jar` file.

Please look at: [How can an app use files inside the JAR for read and write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052311/how-can-an-app-use-files-inside-the-jar-for-read-and-write)

Answer (score 0):

This directory is read-only, to change it:

- Open explorer and go to your src (also files) folder
- Right click, click on properties
- Uncheck read-only
- Launch your jar

One other solution: store your resources in another folder.

Comment: If I Uncheck read-only, is it possible that use like the simple File? I mean is it needed to use input stream? Thanks.

Comment: For any kind of file reading operation you need to have write permissions. And you should be able to write to this file if you disabled read-only.