# The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect - Kotlin - Maven

Tags: java, embedded-resource, kotlin

I get this error when I start my packaged jar. When I run it from my IDE it does not give the error and run.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Development\Kotlin\AccountTool\target\AccountTool-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!\accounts.json (The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.martacus.accounttool.ToolView$handler.readData(Tool.kt:41)
    at com.martacus.accounttool.ToolView.<init>(Tool.kt:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at tornadofx.FXKt.find(FX.kt:238)
    at tornadofx.App.start(App.kt:27)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$52/31866147.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/2900468.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/4210449.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/24077489.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/1828305.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Code and file hierarchy in the ide:
[image]

```
fun readData(){
    accounts.clear()
    var readFile = ToolView::class.java.classLoader.getResource("accounts.json").file
    println(readFile)
    FileReader(readFile).use{
        var account = gson.fromJson(it, Array<Account>::class.java) ?: return
        for(i in account){
            accounts.add(i)
        }
    }

}
```

.jar root:

[image]

I have no idea what is going wrong and why it is giving me the error. Searching on stackoverflow and google didnt provide me with the right answer. I hope someone here can help me, if you need any more info please say so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When a resource is packed into a jar, it is not available as a file in filesystem anymore. Therefore you cannot use standard API for working with filesystem as `File()` or `FileReader()` to access the contents of the resource.

Instead you should open resource stream with [`Class.getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) or [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) methods and read the content from that stream:

```
val stream = ToolView::class.java.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("accounts.json")

stream.reader().use {
    println(it.readText())
}
```

Comment: it might also need to be prefixed with `/` as `/accounts.json` because it is not in the same package as ToolView (then again I don't know what package ToolView is in).  Or use the system classloader instead.

Comment: @JaysonMinard I believe it's required when `getResourceAsStream` is called on a `Class` instance which resolves the name of the resource relative to its package. And here `getResourceAsStream` is invoked on a `ClassLoader`. But anyway, thanks for clarification.

Comment: Thanks! It works! But would this also apply for the WriteFile? Since I didnt change that I did get the error when writing. Atlough i dont see a stream.writer() method.

Comment: @Martacus resources are for bundling read-only data into a jar, so you couldn't write content to a resource. See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5052311/869184

Comment: *"But would this also apply for the WriteFile?"* See [How can an app use files inside the JAR for read and write?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052311/how-can-an-app-use-files-inside-the-jar-for-read-and-write/)