# Java IO: Resource file getting modified in IDE but not in jar

Tags: java, io, outputstream

I am successfully able to read and write to a file in eclipse. I am also able to read from a file in the jar. However, I am not able to write to the file in the jar. It is located in a class folder called res. I have also unzipped the jar file and it contains the file I need to write to but it is not modified after the first run.

How can I do this?

I have tried `BufferedWriter` and `PrintWriter` but no effect. I tried using`FileOutputStream` but I cannot construct it using `getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)` as it returns an `InputStream`.

Comment: Please see this question if it solves your issue: [How can an app use files inside the JAR for read and write?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052311/how-can-an-app-use-files-inside-the-jar-for-read-and-write)

Comment: I have seen this question before and the answers in it did not help me a bit!

Comment: Nothing will help you. What you're attempting is impossible. Resources are read-only. Redesign: rethink.

Comment: I will try to use external file then

Answer (score 0):

Jar is an archive, you are not supposed to write into the file of a jar. 
You write to a file outside and create a jar later.

Comment: Isn't there some relative path to which I can write or read from? I really want it to work in different computers even if the file is outside the jar

Comment: you can use System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") to write to file to tmp directory.

Comment: What should I do then? I am a rookie