# Where do find a File in the Eclipse Project

Tags: java

I know this question has been asked before, but I have a slightly different problem.

I want to read and write to a text file which will be included in my build(.jar file) . its a Gui application java.

Where Should I place the file?
I have placed the file by creating a new Resources folder under the project. This enables me to read the file but when I attempt to write to it, it throws a FileNotFound Exception. What should I do?

I am using this code

```
File file = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("score.txt").getFile());
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
DataOutputStream write = new DataOutputStream(stream);
write.writeInt(max);
```

And for Input i use this :

```
File file = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Files/score.txt").getFile());
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
DataInputStream read = new DataInputStream(input);
System.out.println(read.readInt());
```

For reading this code works perfectly.

[image: Image of my project directory]

Comment: try to reside that text file outside your jar, in en external path

Comment: keep your file in Resource directory if it dont work check the file  permission 755

Comment: Have you add file permission to your manifest?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a resource file from within jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar)

Comment: You might also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052311/how-can-an-app-use-files-inside-the-jar-for-read-and-write

Comment: Can u guys guide me how to change the file permission . And also if i want to keep the file in the C: directory how would i do that